# Energy-efficient cpu usage in multi-core systems

Tags: optimization, cpu

I've a rather theoretical question: Is there a relation between cpu/core usage and the energy consumption. 
I try to explain it in an example:
Lets say we have a set of tasks T and one core C1. C1 would complete the set T within 10 seconds while having a usage of 100%. Can it be more energy efficient to use two cores C1 and C2 and divide the tasks from T among them  so it is still finished in 10 seconds but the usage of C1 and C2  during this time is 50%? (<-- just an example, the numbers are not real)
Like a car has a certain speed where it does not waste to much gas (even though i am aware that a vehicles speed is more equivalet to a cores frequency). 
I although thought that when a cpu/core runs on 100% it gets warm than (lets say) 50%, which means it needs more energy for cooling.

I would be thankful for any comments on this topic

cheers

Answer (score 1):

For CMOS circuits energy depends on number of switches. At the most basic level energy depends on total amount of work but not on CPU load percentage.

But there are some aspects:

1) energy is proportional to square of CPU voltage. OS could lower voltage using technologies like Intel EIST, making 2 x 50% better

2) clock net consumes high amounts of energy regardless of load. OS could lower frequency making 2 x 50% better

3) OS could disable inactive core, making 1 x 100% better. But I don't know such technologies. Probably it is possible for ARMs. I didn't find anything in Google.

2 x 50% looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a very practical and important question in everything from mobiles to HPC, basically any computer that has to worry about operating within a certain power envelope. I’ll try not to talk your ear off.

As a general rule, the faster you can perform a task, the better. Power management in modern processors drop cores into a sleep state (interestingly called Cx where x goes from 1 to n) when idle. The way to consume less power is to maximize the amount of time the cores can spend in a sleep state. The best way to do this is to get the job done as quickly as possible.

Here’s an example: Assume we have a processor with two cores. Each core consumes approximately 30W when executing (non-idle). When in an idle state, let’s say a core consumes 5W. I’m assuming P-states (another power management feature in most modern processors) don’t exist. Let’s look at a 10 sec window. You start executing your app at t=0. Let’s also assume your app is computationally bound, meaning it doesn’t block for I/O or anything else.

Case A (OK): Your app uses one core (core-0) and the other core (core-1) is inactive. So over that 10 sec interval, core-0 uses 30W and consumes 300 Joules of energy. (Energy in Joules = power in watts * time). The other core is idle and consumes only 5W or 50J. So the total energy consumption is 350 J (35W over 10 sec)

Case B (Bad): Your app splits across two cores for 10 sec and neither is idle. Then your total consumption is 60 W (30 W for each core) consuming 600 J. This is quite a bit worse.

Case C (Good): Let’s say that you do some smart multi-threading and can execute your app 4 times faster by distributing threads across both cores. This is pretty reasonable given how most code is poorly threaded even today. Then you get 30W over 2.5sec for both cores, or 225 Joules. This is a reduction by almost 60%.

A 60% reduction in energy usage is a big deal if you are dealing with mobile battery life or powering a data center.

I’ve written a lot about this stuff ranging from the physics to implementation. If you want to know more, take a look at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/list-of-useful-power-and-power-management-articles-blogs-and-references or use your favorite search engine to find me.

Comment: Thanku very much for the answer